# Kubernetes deployment with multiple containers

Tags: kubernetes

I have two containers, `worker` and `dispatcher`.
I want to be able to deploy N copies of `worker` and 1 copy of `dispatcher` to the cluster.
Is there a deployment that will make this work?

`dispatcher` needs to be able to know about and talk to all of the `worker` instances (`worker` is running a web server). However, the external world only needs to talk to `dispatcher`.

As a stretch goal, I'd like to be able to scale N up and down based on demand.

Questions:

1. Should I be using a Deployment or a StatefulSet? or something else?
2. Do I actually need multiple deployments? Can containers from multiple deployments talk to each other?
3. How do I dynamically scale this?

It seems like I can get partway there with a single Deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deploy: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        deploy: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: worker
          image: localhost/worker:latest
```

I expect this will give me 3 workers, but 0 dispatchers. However, if I add `dispatcher` to the `containers` list, I would expect to get 3 of those too, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two containers, worker and dispatcher. I want to be able to
> deploy N copies of worker and 1 copy of dispatcher to the cluster. Is
> there a deployment that will make this work?

Both a Deployment or Statefulset will work.

> dispatcher needs to be able to know about and talk to all of the
> worker instances (worker is running a web server).

This has to do with [Kubernetes Networking plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) and will depend on which plugin your cluster was configured with. Most clusters I have used by default allow traffic across the entire cluster.

> However, the
> external world only needs to talk to dispatcher.

The main ways to do this would be a Service or an Ingress both are explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/).

> I'd like to be able to scale N up and down based on demand.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

> Should I be using a Deployment or a StatefulSet? or something else?

Does your container have state? If so then use a stateful set. The Kubernetes page explains why to use a statefulset https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

> Do I actually need multiple deployments? Can containers from multiple
> deployments talk to each other?

These things are not really related. You would use multiple deployments so you can configure multiple workloads differently.